# How do I send Login information from my web-app and login on another website? Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, https, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a web application using ASP.NET Core MVC. This is a website (website a) that will send a timer result to another website's (website b) database using an API.

However to do this an user should first login on website a and then it should be able to send his information to website b. Since the user already has an account on website b we should be able to send his login credentials to website b and receive an OK response if the credentials are correct.

Does someone maybe have an idea on how I can find an solution for this.

I have tried using website's b Api however I have run into authorization problems.

Comment: Could you please share few relevant snippet so far you are up to now, then it would be easier to assist you further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication methods does website B's API offer? Does it offer OAuth authentication? That's what you'd preferably use. Storing passwords for another website is a big no-no especially since you can't hash them.
With OAuth your user authenticates on website B, who then gives your website A a token to use on the API.

Comment: Since this is an project for an another company we are allowed to store the passwords and hash them in our database. That is why we have two login systems. The first system should send the credentials from website a to website b and receive an response. when we get an OK response we save the users credentials. If website B is down we will use the second system which let's us use the previously saved credentials.

Comment: 1) What authentication methods does website B API offer? This is important to find a proper solution
2) How are you going to reuse the passwords if you store them hashed? Does the API accept passwords in hashed form?